# AIR native process installation before execute

Tags: actionscript-3, command-line, air, png, minify

I'm currently working on an AIR-application, and I make use of a JAR-file for some functionality.

It is very easy to work with a JAR-file, to do so I use the following code:

```
var startupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
startupInfo.executable = myJarFile;
startupInfo.arguments = vectorWithArguments;
```

But now I want to make use of [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/). It's a PNG optimizer you have to install and use via commandline.

The installation goes like this:

1. sudo make install
2. enter password

And after the installation you can optimize an image like this:

```
optipng test.png
```

My question is if I can make use of OptiPNG in my AIR-application? I personally think I can execute the `optipng test.png`, but I'm not sure about the installation.

Hopefully, someone can help me with this. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of hours spending on this issue, I've found out that it isn't possible. As a workaround, I have used an online API to do the work for the application.